PDO errors don't display
Sorry, I'm new to PDO and rusty with PHP. I have a PHP page where I'm trying to display error messages when a PDO call fails. Here's what I have but not even the echo statements after the failure display.
try {
  $conn = new PDO("mysql:host=$servername;dbname=$dbname", $username, $password);
  // set the PDO error mode to exception
  $conn->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
} catch(PDOException $e) {
  echo "Connection failed: " . $e->getMessage();
}

$orderNumber = $_GET['orderID'];
echo "Order number: $orderNumber";

// Get all orders from database for this user
$sql = "SELECT userID, order_files.orderID, order_files.serviceID, SUM(file_total) as orderTotal, date_created FROM order_files
        LEFT JOIN orders ON order_files.orderID = orders.orderID where order_files.orderID = :orderID GROUP BY order_files.orderID";

try {
    $stmt = $conn->prepare($sql);
    
    if (!$stmt) {
    echo "\nPDO::errorInfo():\n";
    print_r($conn->errorInfo());
    }
    
    $stmt->execute(array('orderID' => $orderNumber));
    $results = $stmt->fetchAll();
    var_dump($results);
} catch (PDOException $pdoError) {
    echo "I'm sorry, Dave. I'm afraid I can't do that.";
    throw new error($pdoError->getMessage());
}

What am I missing? I have also tried to move the PDO::errorInfo() block further down after the execute statement as I saw in another answer that it was a potential culprit. No luck.
The page just stops executing everything after $stmt = $conn->prepare($sql);

Check your webserver logs, the error should be detailed there. I'm guessing you don't have error_reporting enabled and you're getting an error other than a PDOException (which is the only thing you're catching.) Alternatively, you might try doing catch (Throwable $e) to cast the widest possible net.

Sorry, this ended up being a dumb question. Needed to modify php.ini to show errors. smacks forehead
